# RollbackException with Spring Web Flow 2.2+/Spring 3.05 and EclipseLink 2.1.2

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, spring-webflow

I have a really weird exception being thrown that's extremely frustrating to track down.  This behavior started when I switched from Hibernate to Eclipselink to satisfy a need for a missing feature.

This seems like some kind of communication miss between Spring and Eclipselink to me, but it may also be a configuration miss on my part. Can you help me figure this out? I'm pulling my hair out over what is probably something very simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@4a73d6bb targetAction = [EvaluateAction@7b16b52c expression = companyDao.listAll(), resultExpression = flowScope.entityList], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'null' of flow 'flows/company/list' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:60)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:534)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.start(RequestControlContextImpl.java:234)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.doEnter(SubflowState.java:101)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    ...
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:476)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    mypackage.GenericDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$945581be.listAll(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:110)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
    org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:534)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.start(RequestControlContextImpl.java:234)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.doEnter(SubflowState.java:101)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction rolled back because transaction was set to RollbackOnly.
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:92)
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    mypackage.GenericDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$945581be.listAll(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:110)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
    org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:155)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:534)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:366)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.start(RequestControlContextImpl.java:234)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.doEnter(SubflowState.java:101)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Here's the method in question:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<entityType> listAll() {
    String entityName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
    if (entityClass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
        Entity ea = (Entity) entityClass.getAnnotation(Entity.class);
        if (ea.name() != null && ea.name().length() > 0) {
            entityName = ea.name();
        }

        // TODO: If this query exists:  entityName + ".list", use it, otherwise:
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        Query query = null;
        try {
            // Try and find a query with the name (EntityName).list
            query = em.createNamedQuery(entityName + ".list");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            try {
                // No query with this name, so fill it in with a custom query
                if (entityClass.getMethod("deletedDate", Date.class) != null) {
                    query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + entityName + " e WHERE deletedDate is null");
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchMethodException();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex1) {
                query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM " + entityName + " e");
            }

        }

        return query.getResultList();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Spring Config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- This will load environmental properties for us as well, filling in
         the necessary data for connecting to an in-memory RDB by default,
         or another DB if supplied properties by the environment -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <!-- System values take priority -->
        <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2" />
        <!-- Check the properties file if we don't find the value in the environment -->
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/memory-database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="url" value="${JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${PARAM1}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${PARAM2}"/>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${PARAM3}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${PARAM4}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Enable aspectj based transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- the transactional advice (i.e. what 'happens'; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="refresh*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="list*" read-only="true"/>
            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:pointcut id="DaoOps" expression="execution(* mypackage.GenericDAO.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="DaoOps"/>
    </aop:config>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" >
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect"/>

    <import resource="webmvc-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="applicationContext-security.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    ... Many Entity Classes Listed Here ...
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Static weaving is in fact being done via an ant task from Maven:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        <java classname="org.eclipse.persistence.tools.weaving.jpa.StaticWeave"
           classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath" fork="true">
                            <arg line="-loglevel FINE -persistenceinfo src/main/resources target/classes target/classes"/>
                        </java>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you catching runtime exception (IllegalArgumentException ) in transactional method? It will mark spring managed transaction for rollback.

Work around

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=IllegalArgumentException.class)
```

Comment: It was the quickest way I could come up with to test for the existence of a Named Query at runtime. In retrospect, I do have a list of persisted entities, and can scan them for @NamedQueries annotations in a similar manned to what JPA does, but it strikes me that there should be a better way to do that.  Testing this solution right now.

Comment: Somehow just doing the noRollbackFor, whether in the xml config, or in @Transactional, did not work.  Thank you for the pointer however, I took the opportunity to re-design the listAll() function to passively use a pre-computed list query, which is computed at instantiation of the Dao. This seems to have solved the issue.